# How to change pages on form submit with React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a registration form set up that is correctly sending data to my back-end on submit, but I can't seem to get the page to change when my handleSubmit function is called.

My `register.js` component

```
import React from 'react';
import useForm from '../form/useForm';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

const Register = () => {

    const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm({
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: "",
            password2: ""
        }, register);

    function register() {
            alert (
                "test"
            )
        console.log(values);
    }

  return (
            <div className="row mt-5">
              <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
                <div className="card card-body">
                  <h1 className="text-center mb-3">
                    <i className="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Register
                  </h1>
                  <form 
                    action="/users/register"
                    method="POST" 
                    onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                      <input 
                      className="form-control" 
                      type="name" 
                      name="name" 
                      onChange={handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Enter Name"
                      value={values.name} 
                      required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                      <input 
                      className="form-control" 
                      type="email" 
                      name="email" 
                      onChange={handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Enter Email"
                      value={values.email} 
                      required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
                      <input 
                      className="form-control" 
                      type="password" 
                      name="password" 
                      onChange={handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Create Password"
                      value={values.password} 
                      required />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="email">Confirm Password</label>
                      <input 
                      className="form-control" 
                      type="password" 
                      name="password2" 
                      onChange={handleChange} 
                      placeholder="Confirm Password"
                      value={values.password2} 
                      required />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                      Register
                    </button>
                  </form>
                  <p className="lead mt-4">Have An Account? <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

My `useForm.js` hook that I'm using to handle the submission

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const useForm = (initialValues, callback) => {

const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
const history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(values)
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch("/users/register", options);
      const responseData = await response.json();
      history.push("/");
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("response ok");
        callback();
      } else {
        console.log("response NOT ok");
        throw new Error(responseData.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setValues(values => ({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
  };

  return {
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    values
  }
};

export default useForm;
```

In the `useForm.js hook`, I threw `history.push("/")` in the `try` block as a test, but it isn't doing anything. What is the best way to handle changing pages on a form submission?

Comment: Remove ```method``` and ```action``` attributes from your ```form``` tag. You already make request with ```fetch``` API in your ```handleSubmit ``` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. Also, you have to define the route.

```
const handleSubmit = async event => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(values)
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch("/users/register", options);
      const responseData = await response.json();
      window.location.href = '/';
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("response ok");
        callback();
      } else {
        console.log("response NOT ok");
        throw new Error(responseData.message);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.response) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: That didn’t seem to do anything. The app remained on the /register page after submitting.

Comment: Can you expand on what “defining the route” means in this context?